# SQL Server: Create new row with only select columns before returning other rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, row

I need to create a CSV file where for each part number, multiple fitments are returned before returning the next part number. The table would look like this:

[image]

I would want each of those fitments repeated for each stockCode. I initially tried just replicating a comma for each column (using a combination of stuff and for xml path), but at 221 columns, the data quickly overflowed and truncated.

Here is the code I am using currently:

```
Select distinct a.stockcode, 'Compatibilty' as relationship,
stuff ((select 'Year=' + cast(c.modelyear as varchar(4)) + '|Make=' + ma.makename + '|'+ mo.modelname, replicate(',',221)
        from database_sourcedata.dbo.products a

        join database_sourcedata.dbo.productfitment b on a.ukey = b.ukey_product
        join database_sourcedata.dbo.dm_fitment c on c.ukey = b.ukey_fitment
        join database_sourcedata.dbo.dm_makes ma on ma.ukey = c.ukey_make
        join database_sourcedata.dbo.dm_models mo on mo.ukey = c.ukey_model
        join database_sourcedata.dbo.dm_trimlevels t on t.ukey = c.ukey_trimlevel
        join database_sourcedata.dbo.dm_drivelines dr on dr.ukey = c.ukey_driveline
        --join database_sourcedata.dbo.productimages b on a.ukey=b.ukey_product
        join #StockCodes sc on a.stockcode = sc.stockcode
        --where a.stockcode = '178010d020'
        for xml path('')),1,0,'') [relationshipdetails]

from 
database_sourcedata.dbo.products a
join database_sourcedata.dbo.productfitment b on a.ukey = b.ukey_product
join database_sourcedata.dbo.dm_fitment c on c.ukey = b.ukey_fitment
join database_sourcedata.dbo.dm_makes ma on ma.ukey = c.ukey_make
join database_sourcedata.dbo.dm_models mo on mo.ukey = c.ukey_model
join database_sourcedata.dbo.dm_trimlevels t on t.ukey = c.ukey_trimlevel
join database_sourcedata.dbo.dm_drivelines dr on dr.ukey = c.ukey_driveline
join #StockCodes sc on a.stockcode = sc.stockcode
group by a.stockcode, c.modelyear, ma.makename, mo.modelname
```

Any ideas? Is my request even clear enough?

Thanks for your help. This is my first post so please forgive breaches of protocol.

Comment: Queries can't change columns for a given row. You could use LAG for each of the columns you don't want to repeat values for. Then if the part number is the same don't include that value. I would also suggest better aliases than a, b, c. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3

Comment: Thanks for that, that's good information. Unfortunately, the alias naming is a house style, but I agree.

I can see how lag would be useful here. What method were you thinking to exclude a part number of the same value?

Comment: Honestly I would do this in the front end, not in the query. It is very painful to do this type of control break logic in a query. The short alias names are fine. It is the a, b, c that is awful. The others you have in there make perfect sense to me.

Comment: Can you recreate the query you posted using the adventure works db?